# Get the default image for a profile2 image field with code

Tags: 7, entities, users

I need to get the fid of the image specified as the default for an image field in a profile2 profile.

There is a [field_get_default_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_default_value/7) function, but it is not clear to me how to use it.

I'm using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to bother with the field_get_default_value function, you can use the [field_info_field](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) function. For image fields, it will provide the fid for the default image in ['settings']['default_image'].

Suppose your field is "field_picture", then this will get you the fid and file:

```
$info = field_info_field('field_picture');
if (!empty($info) && $info['settings']['default_image'] > 0) {
    $default_img_fid  = $info['settings']['default_image'];
    $default_img_file = file_load($default_img_fid);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to add a precision:

Sometimes the default image of an image field is set **specifically** for a particular **content type**, and in this case `field_info_field()` will not give you the right information.

If you're looking for the default image's `fid`, in this case you must use [`field_info_instance()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instance/7)

```
// the entity type is: node, and field name: field_image 
// but it could be something else.
$info = field_info_instance('node', 'field_image', 'machine_name_content_type');
//then it's the same has Whiskey said
if ( !empty( $info ) && $info['settings']['default_image'] > 0 ) {
   $default_fid = $info['settings']['default_image'];
   $default_img_object = file_load( $default_fid );
}
```